# Matlab fminsearch Hessians?

Tags: matlab, data-fitting, fminsearch, hessian-matrix

A warning that Im very new to this and out of my depth, so apologies if this is novice or unclear.

Im estimating parameters using fminsearch for a number of datasets and it has been suggested that we should try to plot hessians for the fit for each dataset. Is it possible to get these using fminsearch?

I was told it should be a standard output option, but as far as I can tell this is not one of the options for fminsearch (although it looks like it IS an option for fminunc)

This is the relevant bit of code Im hoping to modify:

```
 [par,fval] = fminsearch(@(x) logistic(x,arg), [m me p pe c ce]);
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, after some searching, is to use fmincon. For those interested, this is the code that finally worked:

```
[par,fval,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,GRAD,HESSIAN] = fmincon(@(x) logistic(x,arg), [m me p pe c ce], [], [], [], [], [-Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf], [Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf], [], optimopt)
```